# Definition of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

We have the following definition for a conditional expectation:

Let $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a randomn variable on ($\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$. Let $F \subset \Sigma$ be a sub $\sigma-$ algebra, then $Z$ is called a conditional expectation of $X $ under $F$, if $Z$ is $F$ measurable and $\mathbb{E}(X \chi_C) = \mathbb{E}(Z \chi_C)$ for all $C \in F$. What I don't understand here is: What is wrong with $Z=X$? In this case $X$ is $F$ measurable as $X$ is $\Sigma$-measurable and we certainly have $\mathbb{E}(X \chi_C) = \mathbb{E}(X \chi_C)$, so somehow I don't trust this definition. Did I copy anything wrong from the blackboard?

Comment: If $F\subset\Sigma$, the fact that $X$ is $\Sigma$-measurable does not imply that $X$ is $F$-measurable.

Comment: ah, but otherwise this definition is correct?

Comment: Everything before "What I don't understand" is correct, except that one should assume that $X$ is integrable.

Comment: thank you, is there a general equation that defines $Z$? I mean okay, apparently this definition defines $Z$ uniquely, but it does not tell me how I can actually determine $Z$.

Comment: No, there is only this definition--and some special cases such as X F-measurable or X independent of F.

Comment: Yes, there are other definitions. There exists a formal notion of conditional probability given the $\sigma$-algebra $F$, so that we have the intuitive fact that the conditional expectation of $X$ given $F$ is none other than the expectation of $X$ under the conditional probability given $F$. However when $F$ is not the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a discrete random variable this requires technical tools from measure theory (such as the disintegration theorem). The definition you gave might seem less clear at first glance but has the virtue to be much easier to formulate and be understood